# How to filter content of dropdownlist while using enums in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view that an administrator uses to register new users.

When registering the users the administratos has to pick a role that the user will have.

**My problem:**

I have an enum that represent the roles in the dropdownlist and I use the MVC5.1 GetSelectList to populate the lst with the roles from the enum.(code will follow below)

All users have a role and the particullar administrator should not be able to set a developer role on the user he is registering so my question is simply how do i filter this list?

If a user has role "Administrator1" then he should see "readonly, admin, edit" roles and if the user has role "admin2" then he should see "edit, readonly" in the dropdownlist.

**Some code:**

**enum:**

```
public enum OverWatchRoles
{
    Developer = 0,
    Administrator = 1,
    Employee = 2
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Roll", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Roles",
           EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(OverWatchRoles)),
           "Välj Roll",
           new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally build the items you need for building your dropdown by checking the current user role

```
List<SelectListItem> roles = new List<SelectListItem>();     
roles = Enum.GetNames(typeof(OverWatchRoles))
                 .Where(f=>f!=OverWatchRoles.Developer.ToString())
                 .Select(f => new SelectListItem { Value = f, Text = f }).ToList();

ViewBag.Roles = roles;
```

And in your view,

```
@Html.DropDownList("Roles")
```

If you have a view model for your view, you should use that to transfer the data instead of ViewBag.